# Anypoint MQ - are messages persistent by default?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-mq

I am just starting out to use Anypoint MQ and in the past have used Apache ActiveMQ.
In case of Apache ActiveMQ , Mule connector provides an option where we can choose if we want to publish a message as `Persistent` Vs `NonPersistent`

Dont see that option with `Publish` connector for AnypointMQ

Tried googling but am not getting any details regarding the same ....
any pointers would be appreciated .. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anypoint MQ doesn't used that terminology or has an equivalent feature. Having said that it always operates in a similar way to ActiveMQ persistent mode. You can find it in the public [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mq/mq-understanding):

> Because the storage solution for Anypoint MQ is durable, messages that were already in the Anypoint MQ system before service was interrupted are retained.